# Real time sync from sharepoint to sql server

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint

I've seen many solutions to sync SQL Server data TO SharePoint, but nothing to sync SharePoint lists to SQL Server.

Does anyone know of a solution? Commercial is fine.

Alternatively, I'll need to write a web part that creates relationships between multiple SharePoint lists.  Unfortunately, Some are InfoPath libraries with no lookup fields so I can't use the SPQuery CAML joins.

I've found the Camelot .NET Connector but the syntax doesn't seem to support joins, and the SLAM! SharePoint List Association Manager which may work for me but would rather just sync the data to SQL Server and create my reports from there.

EDIT: 
SLAM! SharePoint List Association Manager does what I was looking for in real time.

Comment: The upcoming version of Camelot .NET Connector supports Joins, check with the development team when it's ready or if you can get hold of nightly build, http://www.bendsoft.com/contact-us/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own SSIS ETL process to extract the list data from SharePoint and load it into SQL server tables. There is a free SharePoint list adapter on codeplex to assist with this. Take a look at [SharePoint List Source and Destination](http://sqlsrvintegrationsrv.codeplex.com/releases/view/17652)

Comment: I've used this before for batch moves but don't have the time to figure out the real-time aspect of it. When I installed and tried the SLAM! SharePoint List Association Manager it worked perfectly.  I hate unanswered questions though and I'm sure this would work so marking this as answer and considering this question closed.  Thanks.