# SQL server connecting to SharePoint server

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, ssis, sharepoint-2013, etl

I wish to connect SQL server 2012 to SharePoint server.  This do complete SQL queries..what is the easy way to do so please?

I want to download data from a SharePoint table into SQL server table basically.

I can only find tutorials connecting SharePoint to SQL server. I want the other way around

Happy to do this via SSIS too..

Please help

Comment: You can use https://www.cozyroc.com/ssis/sharepoint-source.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Real time sync from sharepoint to sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855127/real-time-sync-from-sharepoint-to-sql-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three options to read from Sharepoint table:

### (1) Using ODATA Components

You can use ODATA Source component to access to the Sharepoint Lists

- [Using the SSIS OData Source Connector with SharePoint Online](https://sharepointsolutiontips.blogspot.com/2016/07/using-ssis-odata-source-connector-with.html)
- [Using the OData Source in SQL Server Integration Services](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3220/using-the-odata-source-in-sql-server-integration-services/)
- [Connecting to SharePoint from SSIS using OData Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42259319/connecting-to-sharepoint-from-ssis-using-odata-source)

### (2) Using Sharepoint List adapter

You can simply use the Sharepoint List adapter components which are an open source project created by SQL Server community within a project called *MSSQL SSIS Community*:

You can check the project page at the following link:

- [MsSQL SSIS Community](https://github.com/fan130/mssql-ssis-community-samples)

Or you can simply download the assemblies from the link below:

- [Project Releases](https://github.com/fan130/mssql-ssis-community-samples/releases)

You can read more about this components in the following link:

- [Extracting and Loading SharePoint Data in SQL Server Integration Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/hh368261(v=msdn.10))

### (3) Using third party components

- [KingswaySoft SSIS Integration Toolkit for Microsoft SharePoint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KingswaySoft.SSISIntegrationToolkitforMicrosoftSharePoint)
- [AxioWorks SQList](http://www.axioworks.com/sqlist/?lipi=urn%3Ali%3Apage%3Ad_flagship3_pulse_read%3BhTS8%2FvDSRQ%2BUYgjUeovuZQ%3D%3D)

Comment: Thank you x. Going to have a look at the Odata x

Answer (score 0):

If you have [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=13255) installed, you can use OPENROWSET command in a View.

I have created a View using OPENROWSET command. Below is the syntax I used, you need to replace the text enclosed in <> with your values:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'WSS;IMEX=1;RetrieveIds=Yes;DATABASE=https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/<sitename>;LIST=<listID>;', 'select <columns list> from <list name as displayed in SharePoint>')
```

You will need SharePoint List ID that you can get easily by opening the list in browser and going to Settings, and checking the URL.. it is in format: {247c5fd8-32cd-4536-b1d0-e2e62845f174}. Please check [this link](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Get-the-ID-of-a-SharePoint-list/td-p/367619).