# Sharepoint List Adaptor - ssis 2010

Tags: sharepoint, ssis

I have been searching all over the internet for a SharePoint List adaptor.

I am using SSIS 2010, and I wish to connect to SharePoint list as a source.

I cannot find the correct adaptor or MSI to do this

can someone please help point me in the right direction

I am basic using SSIS 2010

Please help

I have tried this link, but the MSI does not work

https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=sqlsrvintegrationsrv

Comment: Try another method to connect to Sharepoint: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56476238/sql-server-connecting-to-sharepoint-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [this SharePoint adapter](https://www.kingswaysoft.com/products/ssis-integration-toolkit-for-microsoft-sharepoint) from Kingswaysoft, and it works great.  It's free to try in Visual Studio.  You need a license once you're running it on a SQL Server.

If you only need to read from the list—and you're using SharePoint online or on-premise version 2016 or greater—take a look at [this tutorial](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-configure-odata-ssis-connection-for-sharepoint-online/) using the built-in OData source.

Comment: this worked amazing. However , I wish to download data from a direct version history, page. how is this possible please? @bottomsnap

Comment: Sorry, I haven't had to pull data from version history before.